# ImportError: No module named rfc822 pyramid python

Tags: python, pyramid

When I attempt to run pyramid

```
[~/env/MyStore]# ../bin/pserve development.ini
```

It will show the following error

```
File "/home/vretinfo/env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/Paste-1.7.5.1-py3.2.egg/paste/fileapp.py", line 14, in <module>
    from paste.httpheaders import *
File "/home/vretinfo/env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/Paste-1.7.5.1-py3.2.egg/paste/httpheaders.py", line 140, in <module>
    from rfc822 import formatdate, parsedate_tz, mktime_tz
ImportError: No module named rfc822
```

How should I resolve this?

---

This is what I did to install

```
$ mkdir opt
$ cd opt
$ wget http://python.org/ftp/python/3.2.3/Python-3.2.3.tgz 
$ tar -xzf Python-3.2.3.tgz
$ cd Python-3.2.3
```

./configure --prefix=$HOME/opt/Python-3.2.3

```
$ make; 
$ make install
$ cd ~
$ wget http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
$ pico distribute_setup.py
* change first line to opt/Python-3.2.3/python
$ opt/Python-3.2.3/bin/python3.2 distribute_setup.py
$ opt/Python-3.2.3/bin/easy_install virtualenv
$ opt/Python-3.2.3/bin/virtualenv --no-site-packages env
$ cd env
$ ./bin/pip install passlib
$ ./bin/pip install pyramid_beaker
$ ./bin/pip install pyramid_mailer
$ ./bin/pip install pyramid_mongodb
$ ./bin/pip install pyramid_jinja2
$ ./bin/pip install Werkzeug
$ ./bin/pip install pyramid 
$ ./bin/pcreate -s pyramid_mongodb MyShop
$ cd MyShop
$ ../bin/python setup.py develop
$ ../bin/python setup.py test -q
```

---

Ok, I've done some searching around on pyramid docs ( http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/paste.html ). 
It states on the 3rd paragraph

> "However, all Pyramid scaffolds render PasteDeploy configuration files, to provide new developers with a standardized way of setting deployment values, and to provide new users with a standardized way of starting, stopping, and debugging an application."

So I made changes to development.ini and replaced

```
[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
```

and in setup.py, I added 'waitress' into the requires array

Next step, I did to totally remove all things related to Paste, in /home/vretinfo/env/ECommerce/,

```
$ rm -rf Paste*;rm -rf paste*
```

After this, I tried running test -q again, this is the stack trace:

```
[~/env/ECommerce]# ../bin/python setup.py test -q

/home/vretinfo/opt/Python-3.2.3/lib/python3.2/distutils/dist.py:257: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'paster_plugins'
warnings.warn(msg)
running test
Checking .pth file support in .
/home/vretinfo/env/ECommerce/../bin/python -E -c pass
Searching for Paste>=1.7.1
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/Paste/
Reading http://pythonpaste.org
Best match: Paste 1.7.5.1
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/P/Paste/Paste-1.7.5.1.tar.gz#md5=7ea5fabed7dca48eb46dc613c4b6c4ed
Processing Paste-1.7.5.1.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-q5h5rn/Paste-1.7.5.1/setup.cfg
Running Paste-1.7.5.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-q5h5rn/Paste-1.7.5.1/egg-dist-tmp-e3nvmj
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/_build/_sources'
```

It seems like paste is needed for pyramid1.4 for some reason. Perhaps someone have some insights on this.

Comment: Considering that you built python with standard config options, try `ls /usr/lib/python3.2 | grep "rfc822"`. What's your output there?

Comment: @eazar001: The module has been removed in Python 3. Paste is *not* python 3 compatible, I am surprised to see it used.

Comment: What version of Pyramid is this? The `Paste` dependency has been removed a few versions ago *because it doesn't work on Python 3*.

Comment: I'm surprised to see it being installed as well, as I am simply following the instructions on the installation in http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/install.html#installing-chapter

Comment: I've added in steps I've taken to install pyramid from ground up

Comment: edited the question further regarding Paste

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve this issue through the folks in IRC#pyramid. I'm posting the solution in here in case someone encounters in future. I've tested this out in Python3.2, works ok now.

After running ./bin/pcreate -s <...>

in the folder of the project, development.ini

Change the following:

```
    1. in the 1st line, rename [app:<Project>] to [app:main]

    2. [server:main]
       If it is egg:Paste#http, change it to

       use = egg:waitress#main

    3. remove [pipeline:main] and its section
```

in the same folder, make the necessary changes to setup.py:

```
    1. requires = [....], add in waitress into the array, remove WebError from the array
    2. remove paster_plugins=['pyramid']
```

Then finally, run

```
    $ ../bin/python setup.py develop
```

Paste will not be installed or checked if it exists.